# Inspect single letter in Google Chrome Inspector or Firebug

Tags: html, css, web-inspector

I am working on a template that has a lot of existing CSS. One of the things that the CSS does is enlarges and bolds the first letter of the first paragraph of an article. I am assuming this is a pseudo class (like :first-letter) but I can't seem to find it in the CSS stylesheets.

I can't inspect a single letter in the Inspector or Firebug because it's not wrapped in an HTML tag and the

tag it is in has different styling than this one letter.

Is there a way to inspect an element for all of it's pseudo elements or inspect a single letter in a

element? Thanks!

Comment: [:first-letter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter) is the correct pseudo class. Just look for that when inspecting the parent element.

Comment: Even if it is not wrapped in a HTML tag you can simply mouseover on it using chrome inspector and try to look at all the css elements on the right .. Already tried that ?

Comment: @DrydenLong, the only CSS selector using first-letter is commented out (I've even deleted it to try) and no luck. Are there other CSS selectors that could do that?

Comment: If the site is live, go ahead and paste the link. It'd be helpful.

Comment: @EnigmaRM, unfortunately it's not but if we go live without resolution of this, I will post it.

Answer (score 12):

if you inspect the element that the pseudo-class is on, and scroll down in the styles pane, it will show all associated pseudo classes.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a way to have Chrome identify ALL psuedo selectors. But I'd just do a search in Chrome for `:first-letter` (that's likely the styling that you're looking for - unless it's JS based)

From the DevTools, push `ctrl` + `shift` + `f` and then search for `:first-letter`

This should search all files within the website. If you only had one CSS file, you could just navigate to it via the *sources* tab. and then just do `ctrl` + `f` to search that one file.

You may also try one of these others. The ones that stand out to me: `first-letter`, `nth-letter`, `first-letter`, `first-word`

List of all the psuedos from [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/):

```
:first-child        :first-of-type        :only-child
:last-child         :last-of-type         :only-of-type                  
:nth-child          :nth-of-type    
:nth-last-child     :nth-last-of-type

::first-letter      ::first-line          ::first-word
::last-letter       ::last-line           ::last-word
::nth-letter        ::nth-line            ::nth-word
::nth-last-letter   ::nth-last-line       ::nth-last-word
```

If it's not one of those, then it's time to start looking at JavaScript. To rule JS out, I'd just disable JS all together and see if that affects your issue.

Comment: I had tried that and searched for first-letter and first-of-type and there's only one CSS selector that shows up which I've commented out completely.

Comment: Are there other CSS classes that could control the first letter of a paragraph?

Comment: @MxmastaMills `::nth-letter` is another one.